# Javascript append string dynamically to script element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I append the following variable within my html (as part of script tag).

```
var x = '-----BEGIN CERT\nMIIDvTCCAqWgAsdfsdfTAktS\nMR4wHAYDVQQKExVTb2Z0Zm9ydW0gQ29yc45656b24xHjAcBgNVBAsTFVNlY3Vy\naXR5IFJORCBEaXZpc2lvbQQKDAhq\ncG1vcmdhbjER\n-----END CERT-----\n;';
```

I am getting an invalid token error with the below code;

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.innerHTML = "var x = '-----BEGIN CERT\nMIIDvTCCAqWgAsdfsdfTAktS\nMR4wHAYDVQQKExVTb2Z0Zm9ydW0gQ29yc45656b24xHjAcBgNVBAsTFVNlY3Vy\naXR5IFJORCBEaXZpc2lvbjEcMBoGA1UEAxMTU29mdGZvcnVtIFB1YmxpYyBDQTE\nODQzMzhaFw0yMj45645gNVBAYTAktSMREwDwYDVQQKDAhq\ncG1vcmdhbjER\n-----END CERT-----\n;';";
                $("body").append( script );
```

Comment: You trying to set something which is not javascript, but you are specified type of javascript. So...

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the carriage returns.  Also as @maxzoom suggests, you probably want to use innerText rather than innerHTML.

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.innerHTML = "var x = '-----BEGIN CERT\\nMIIDvTCCAqWgAsdfsdfTAktS\\nMR4wHAYDVQQKExVTb2Z0Zm9ydW0gQ29yc45656b24xHjAcBgNVBAsTFVNlY3Vy\\naXR5IFJORCBEaXZpc2lvbjEcMBoGA1UEAxMTU29mdGZvcnVtIFB1YmxpYyBDQTE\\nODQzMzhaFw0yMj45645gNVBAYTAktSMREwDwYDVQQKDAhq\\ncG1vcmdhbjER\\n-----END CERT-----\\n;'; console.log(x);";
  $("body").append(script);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here from the inspector is it working in action...

[image]

Comment: Thx...But I see that the var x = is not getting printed

Comment: I just tried the "run code snippet" in Chrome, FF and Edge and the "cert" is printer/logged for me here.  Anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

To handle embedded expressions such as new line character `\n` in a string you could use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) notation as below:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
var content = "var x = `-----BEGIN CERT\nMIIDvTCCAqWgAsdfsdfTAktS\nMR4wHAYDVQQKExVTb2Z0Zm9ydW0gQ29yc45656b24xHjAcBgNVBAsTFVNlY3Vy\naXR5IFJORCBEaXZpc2lvbjEcMBoGA1UEAxMTU29mdGZvcnVtIFB1YmxpYyBDQTE\nODQzMzhaFw0yMj45645gNVBAYTAktSMREwDwYDVQQKDAhq\ncG1vcmdhbjER\n-----END CERT-----\n`;";
content += "console.log(x);";
script.innerHTML = content;
$("body").append(script);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When viewing generated source in browser the script is present in **body** element:

[image]

Comment: I think you might still need to use "\\n" rather than "\n" though for the correct result.

Comment: Please see the snippet output. I've also run a stand-alone test with no problem.

Comment: Take a look at the script block that is created and compare it to one created with "\\n" rather than "\n".  I guess it boils down to weather or not one wants the resulting script block to be escaped or not.  My guess is that they do, but if not then your solution is fine as is.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way:

```
var x = '-----BEGIN CERT\nMIIDvTCCAqWgAsdfsdfTAktS\nMR4wHAYDVQQKExVTb2Z0Zm9ydW0gQ29yc45656b24xHjAcBgNVBAsTFVNlY3Vy\naXR5IFJORCBEaXZpc2lvbjEcMBoGA1UEAxMTU29mdGZvcnVtIFB1YmxpYyBDQTE\nODQzMzhaFw0yMj45645gNVBAYTAktSMREwDwYDVQQKDAhq\ncG1vcmdhbjER\n-----END CERT-----\n;'

var script = `<script type="text/javascript">${x}</script>`

$("body").append(script);
```